# Playing audio files continually using audio recorded url

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, avplayerlayer

I am newcomer in Objective-C and have experience only 12 months in iPhone development.

I am recording audio files in One `UIViewController`, and playing on another `UIViewController`. For playing purpose i am saving the date string for generation of  url,it is fine working properly,
 But ,now my problem is i want to play previous audio record file for some time after that i want to play next audio file using url . i am saving all the data using nsuser dafaults please help me

```
NSM![enter image description here][1]utableArray *dateString;
NSURL recordFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingString:[self.dateString objectAtIndex:sender.tag]]];
For playing

player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:recordFile error:&error];
```

from fig when i click a tag 2 i want to play first 5 sec tag1 after that i want to play tag2

Answer (score 0):

Record the audio -> Save the audio in the Temp -> Track the saved path of the audio file (You can store this saved path in an array) . Repeat the same steps for the next file.

Use `AVQueuePlayer`for playing items one after the other.